# How to create a Docker development that all projects can access?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, environment, docker-container

I'm trying to create a general docker development environment, but having some issues with it. My goal is to have only one container that I can use for any related project that I have.

For example, instead of installing python in my computer I'd like to use a container with python installed. The idea is that all of my python projects would communicate with this container to access the python environment.

In the future I want to have a docker-compose with containers for python, node.js, flutter, and so on... A single docker compose with all of the development environment I need.

Thing is, I'm not able to create a python environment that's accessible to all my projects. I've tried to use Remote Containers in vscode, so I don't have to install python locally, and it works, but in parts. I have to create a Dockerfile for the project and when it runs it creates a container for it.

I can't access that container with other projects, and if I try to do the same process in other project it will create another container. Each project needs to have their own Dockerfile and a container running python.

Is there a way to create one single container where all projects can access and use python? Is this idea even viable?

Comment: What benefit would doing this in Docker bring?  I can imagine a bunch of obvious downsides: IDEs can't directly access the interpreters; you need special Docker-specific setup to do anything; most operations would require root access.  There are established tools like Packer and Vagrant that attempt this; you can also use a general-purpose system automation tool like Ansible, Salt Stack, or Chef to reproducibly install software on the host system directly.

Comment: And not to mention: each container need resources.

Comment: I guess it's not so viable then. I thought that doing this I would be able to prepare a complete enviroment where a person would only need one container to run any project.

Comment: For example, if I have some node.js projects they would communicate with a container where node is installed, each project would have their node_modules with all the resources they need. the computer would be isolated from the development enviroment

Comment: As mentioned my goal was to have a docker compose with all of those containers. So all of the enviroment would be ready with one command. It would start containers with python, node.js, flutter, ruby.... Eliminating the need of the user to install, prepare and configure each enviroment

Comment: IDEs would be able to communicate through [Remote - Containers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers) extension in vscode

Comment: @SamuelG. in the Node example, each application has its own `./node_modules` directory, so it's implicitly isolated from other application and the system's Node installation; you don't need Docker for this, especially in development.  Other languages tend to have similar non-container isolation mechanisms (Python virtual environments, Ruby rvm gemsets and Bundler vendor trees, the Go module system, ...).

Comment: Yes, they are isolated, but for those projects to work the person has to have node.js in ther pc. I'd like to separate that. Imagine a new pc. The person would just run a docker compose up and docker would prepare a container with node, other with python... So the person could just have docker with those containers

Comment: I had this idea because I needed to format the pc and was struggling to set everything up. So i thought that I could put node, and others, in a container. In this case the set up would be much faster. Just having to run that docker compose

Comment: Each project have their node modules, venv.... But node, python, ruby and others would be in containers ready to use.